# Google analytics: Can I track HTML section displays in a one-page website?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a one page website consisting on:

```
<body>
  <section id="#section1"> content here </section>
  <section id="#section2"> content here </section>
  <section id="#section3"> content here </section>
  <section id="#section4"> content here </section>
</body>
```

With Google Analytics, is there a way to know when a user reaches a specific section? In the end, I want to know if users who go to my website scroll until the bottom or not.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do this with scroll tracking. The simpler method would be to track when the user has reached the bottom, but to see if they viewed certain sections of the page may require a bit more JavaScripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin called [Scroll Depth](http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/), which you plug in your HTML sections and have events fire when a user reaches that. Here is what the configuration looks like:

```
jQuery.scrollDepth({
  elements: ['#section1', '#section2','#section3', '#section4']
});
```